# what does the - operator do with char *?

Tags: c, string

I new to C. I am reading a find-replace algorithm for C and I am a bit confused what the `-` & `+` operators do in this code:

```
char *replace(char * src, const char * search, const char * replace) {
   char * buffer = malloc(4096);  //allocate 4096 bytes in memory to new string
   char * p; //substring of my search in the src string
   int i;

   p = strstr(src, search);
   if ( NULL == p ) return src; if // 'search' not found on 'src' return src
      i =  p - src; //index of my substring

   strncpy(buffer, src, i); //copy the substring value to buffer
   sprintf(buffer + i, "%s%s", replace, 
   p + strlen(search)); // ???

   return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Look up "pointer arithmetics" in google.

Comment: @littleadv et al: why do we continue to advocate looking up programming questions in Google? We _want_ Google to point to SO for those.

Comment: @paxdiablo because some questions are too broad to answer. Pointer arithmetics is IMHO way too much to explain in an answer on SO.

Comment: @paxdiablo Starting with [the web search engine of your choice] is always the right thing to do, which is why we want the search engines to point to SO when SO has the best answer. But SO is the wrong place to explain programming *topics*; it's for *specific* programming questions. In this case there's a specific question about a piece of code, and the appropriate answer is "look up pointer arithmetic".

Comment: I agree with the contention that some questions are too broad but I'm not sure I agree that this is one of them. This is a _very_ specific question about what the subtraction is doing in the given code. In any case, I would think even the broad "how does pointer arithmetic work in C?" would be suitable as well : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+pointer+arithmetic - there are close to 3000 of them :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `p` is a location in your character array (string) and `src` is the start of it,

```
i = p - src;
```

will set `i` to the index at which `p` points.

For example, consider the following memory layout:

```
 [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8]  [9]  <-- Indexes
 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131  132  <-- Addresses
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| H | i | , |   | w | o | r | l | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
  ^               ^
  |               |
 src              p
```

In this case, `p - src` will give you `127 - 123` or `4`, which is the index of the `w` within `"Hi, world"`.

This is called pointer arithmetic is covered in `Additive operators` in the ISO standard (`C99 6.5.6/9`):

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.

It provides a scaled way of working out differences *within the same array or with one pointing just beyond the end of the array* (all else is undefined).

By that I mean doing pointer arithmetic with (for example) four-byte integers, will give you a difference of *one* between the addresses of `arr[7]` and `arr[8]`, not four as some may think.

The `buffer + i` construct is simply another way of saying `&(buffer[i])`, the address of the `i`th element of the array `buffer`. I actually prefer the latter method since it seems more explicit in what I'm trying to represent.

For what it's worth, that's not actually a very good string replacement code. It has numerous problems:

- if no replacements are made, you have a 4K memory leak with `buffer`.
- in any case, you should *always* check to ensure `malloc` hasn't failed.
- you have a possibility of buffer overflow the way the new string is allocated, you should really allocate based on the lengths of `src` `search` and `replace`.
- you could create the new string with a single `sprintf ("%*.*s%s%s", i, i, src, replace, &(src[i + strlen (search)]));` or a `strcpy` and two `strcat` operations. Mixing the two seems incongruous to me.

Comment: I admire your effort, but I think that someone who's not familiar with pointers (as OP seems to be), it won't help all that much.

Comment: @littleadv, there ya' go, hopefully that diagram will make it a little clearer for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

it is a simple pointer arithmetics.

`buffer + i` is the substring of `buffer`, that starts from the `i`th character [until the end]

`p - src` is giving you the offset between `p` to `src`.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is just a pointer - an integer value.

The `+` and `-` operators work exactly as you'd expect - they increment or decrement the value of the pointer.

If you think of strings as a contiguous array of chars, you're just talking about a location within that string.

Answer (score 0):

Read more on pointer arithmetic.

Basically `+` for `char *`:

```
a=a+1  =>  a=(char *) ( (int)a + sizeof(char) )
```